# Selection by user before segue

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

In my navigation bar, i got a '+' for adding a new object. But before the program switch to the new ViewController when pressing the '+' (Step 1), i would like the user to make an input as shown in Step 2. But i don't know what the sequence is called? Or how to make it.

I'll be looking forward to hear from you :).

Step 1:

[image: Navigation bar]

Step 2:
[image]

Comment: dont use a segue directly from the "+". Use an action handler, present the UIAlertView and in the actions in the alert view trigger the required segue

Comment: Great. Thank you Paulw11!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Add a segue from your present view controller to the next view controller and give it some identifier (suppose "gotoNext").

2) On "+" action, open an action sheet using UIAlertViewConroller (reference [link](http://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/)) :

```
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "This is my message.", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (action) in
        // ...
    }
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action) in
        // ...perform any functionality here (e.g. - perform your segue here)
        performSegueWithIdentifier("gotoNext", sender: self)
    }
    alertController.addAction(OKAction)

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {
        // ...
    }

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if "gotoNext" == segue.identifier {
          // this is where you can pass any data to the next view controller.
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: It's already fixed. I just had to know the name 'Alert' :-P.

But thanks for the good explanation!